# for every $x$ , $|x-x_0|<ɛ \implies |f(x)-f(x_0)|<δ$ , Does $f(x)$ Continuous function?

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

> Let $f(x)$ defined in all $\mathbb{R}$ , for every $ɛ>0$ there is $δ>0$ so that for every $x$ , $|x-x_0|<ɛ \implies |f(x)-f(x_0)|<δ$ , Does $f(x)$ Continuous in $x_0$?

the definition of Continuous function is :

$$|x-x_0|<δ \implies |f(x)-f(x_0)|<ɛ$$

so I think that $f(x)$ not continuous in $x_0$

but Which feature $f$ expresses the  condition in the environmental of a given $x_0$?

Comment: By your statement, as it is, you can't choose what $\delta$ is. In fact, your statement is true for all functions $f$ when $\delta = \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition  does not imply that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=x_0$. It does not imply the continuity of f(x) at any other point. Note that there is always a $\delta$ such that$ |x-x_0|<ɛ \implies |f(x)-f(x_0)|<δ$.

Comment: I got it , and this is why f(x) not continuous  at $x_0$ , but witch feature of f expresses the conditions  in the environmental of a given $x_0$ ?

Comment: As long as  $ |x-x_0|<ɛ$   or $ |x-x_0|<\delta$, $x$ is in some neighborhood  of $x_0$ but that is not the point. The point is the implication that if $x$ is close enough to $ x_0$ then $f(x)$ is as close as you wish to $ f(x_0)$.